# How to add products to a company?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

In my company form, I would like to be able to add products directly. Basically, a company can have many products.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_products
  has_many :products, :through => :company_products

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

My Form:

```
<%= form_for(@company) do |f| %>

  <ul>

    <li class="clearfix">
      <%= f.label :company_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :company_name %>
    </li>

    <li>
      <%= f.collection_select :product_ids, Product.all, :id, :name, { :prompt => 'Select a product' } %>
    </li>

    <li>
      <%= f.collection_select :product_ids, Product.all, :id, :name, { :prompt => 'Select a product' } %>
    </li>

    <li>
      <%= f.collection_select :product_ids, Product.all, :id, :name, { :prompt => 'Select a product' } %>
    </li>
 ....
```

Above, does not exactly work. Since it only adds the product that was selected in the last `f.collection_select`.

This is what I am trying to achieve. In console, I do:

```
company.update_attributes({"product_ids"=>["1", "2", "3"]})
```

Which would assign products with id: 1, 2 and 3 to the specified company.

What is the proper way to do this in Rails 3?

**EDIT**

In my form, it works with:

```
<%= f.collection_select :product_ids, Product.all, :id, :name, { :prompt => 'Select a product'},{ :multiple => true } %>
```

Is there a way to do this with select dropdown boxes instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nested forms for products:

<%= fields_for @company.products do |product_fields| %>
  <%= product_fields.collection_select :product_id, Product.all, :id, :name, { :prompt => 'Select a product' } %>
<% end %>

Comment: undefined method `product_ids[]' for #<Company:0x00000104c687c0>. The first argument needs to be a relation

Comment: Fixed some typos on your new suggestion, which would have otherwise thrown a few errors. Second, your suggestion passes `products_attributes` which is meant more for updating, than creating

Comment: @Christian Fazzini, if you use accepts_nested_attributes_for in model then you should use fields_for helper in your forms. See http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 and http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: I've seen both railscasts before. That only works with `has_many`, not `has_many :products, :through => :company_products`